# Parse String Output to File

Tags: java, android, string, split

The first part of this “Frankenstein-ed” Java works perfectly, however the second part outputs some jumbled nonsense.  So the variable  of result will be my input from the user.   I had to first UpperCase the string before I did the parsing for some dumb reason, it’s hard when you come from the Database/Analysis background and know you do something in seconds and not get an error... I gave credit where credit is due within the code...

myfile.txt ---> [Ljava.lang.String;@19821f

```
  import java.io.*;
/*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29*/

  public class StringParser {

  public static void main (String arg[])
     throws FileNotFoundException {
String result = "eggs toast bacon bacon butter ice beer".toUpperCase();
  String[] resultU = result.split("\\s");
  String[] y = resultU;

  {
for (int x=0; x< resultU.length; x++)



    System.out.println(resultU[x]);


  /*http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java103/java103.html#output*/

            FileOutputStream out; // declare a file output object
            PrintStream p; // declare a print stream object

            try
            {
                    // Create a new file output stream
                    // connected to "myfile.txt"
                    out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

                    // Connect print stream to the output stream
                    p = new PrintStream( out );

                    p.println (resultU);

                    p.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realize you're overwriting the same file for each element in your array?

You should use

```
out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt", true); // appends to existing file
```

As well as printing the actual element, not the String representation of the *whole* array

```
p.println(resultU[x]);  // resultU without index prints the whole array - yuk!
```

Although you should probably update your code to only create the output File *once* and just write each element of the array to the same output stream, as the current method is a bit inefficient.

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String result = "eggs toast bacon bacon butter ice beer".toUpperCase();

    PrintStream p = null;

    try {
        p = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"));

        for (String s : result.split("\\s")) {
            p.println(s);
            p.flush(); // probably not necessary
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // should really use a logger instead!
    } finally {
        try {
            p.close(); // wouldn't need this in Java 7!
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Java so I'm trying to learn by putting my feet to the fire... :) Thanks.. let me try it out...

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate the array and write each element one after one.

```
FileOutputStream out; // declare a file output object
  PrintStream p; // declare a print stream object
  try
   {
   out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");
   p = new PrintStream( out );
   for(String str:resultU)
    {
        p.println (str);
     }
   p.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
   }
```

Comment: I'm new to Java so I'll take a look on how to do this.

Comment: Since the streams are getting closed within the `try` block, I'd recommend putting the declaration inside of it too. But then your code is almost exactly mine. Almost no difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
p.println (resultU);
```

is printing a string representation of the array itself, not the elements in it. To print the elements, you'll need to loop through the array and print them out individually. [The Arrays class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) has a convenience method to do this for you, of course.

Answer (score 0):

That "jumbled non-sense" is the `String`s location in memory, but that's not important right now.

The solution to your problem is this:

```
try {
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt", true);
  PrintStream = new PrintStream(out);

  for(String s : resultU)
    p.println(s);

  p.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This replaces your entire `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought the "jumbled nonsense" was something computer-wise.  Thanks!